# lightdm not able to authenticate: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied

Tags: 18.04, gnome, login, lightdm, dbus

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 I can't login using the lightdm Interface:

I tried the suggestions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) (check permissions and reinstall/restart lightdm) but no change.

These are the things that I could find in the logs:

- `syslog`

```
Jan  8 15:39:25 penny lightdm[1513]: Failed to write utmpx: Permission denied
Jan  8 15:39:25 penny lightdm[1513]: Error writing to daemon: Bad file descriptor
Jan  8 15:39:25 penny lightdm[1513]: message repeated 2 times: [ Error writing to daemon: Bad file descriptor]
Jan  8 15:39:25 penny lightdm[1513]: Failed to write utmpx: Permission denied
Jan  8 15:39:25 penny gnome-session-c[2880]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-2E3GCThPiA: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
Jan  8 15:39:30 penny gnome-session[2775]: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Jan  8 15:39:30 penny gnome-session[2775]:   Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Jan  8 15:39:30 penny gnome-session[2775]:   Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Jan  8 15:39:30 penny gnome-session[2775]:   Value in failed request:  0x0
Jan  8 15:39:30 penny gnome-session[2775]:   Serial number of failed request:  19
Jan  8 15:39:30 penny gnome-session[2775]:   Current serial number in output stream:  20
Jan  8 15:39:30 penny gnome-session[2775]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GL Helper exited with code 256
Jan  8 15:39:30 penny gnome-session-c[2882]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-2E3GCThPiA: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
Jan  8 15:39:30 penny [2882]: eglGetDisplay() failed
Jan  8 15:39:30 penny gnome-session[2775]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GLES Helper exited with code 256
Jan  8 15:39:30 penny gnome-session-c[2883]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-2E3GCThPiA: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session[2775]: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session[2775]:   Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session[2775]:   Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session[2775]:   Value in failed request:  0x0
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session[2775]:   Serial number of failed request:  19
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session[2775]:   Current serial number in output stream:  20
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session[2775]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GL Helper exited with code 256
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session-c[2885]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-2E3GCThPiA: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session-c[2885]: eglGetDisplay() failed
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session[2775]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GLES Helper exited with code 256
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session[2775]: gnome-session-binary[2775]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Der Kindprozess wurde mit Status 1 beendet
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session[2775]: gnome-session-binary[2775]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session-binary[2775]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Der Kindprozess wurde mit Status 1 beendet
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session-binary[2775]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny lightdm[1513]: Failed to write utmpx: Permission denied
Jan  8 15:39:35 penny gnome-session-c[2991]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-2E3GCThPiA: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
Jan  8 15:39:40 penny gnome-session[2886]: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Jan  8 15:39:40 penny gnome-session[2886]:   Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Jan  8 15:39:40 penny gnome-session[2886]:   Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Jan  8 15:39:40 penny gnome-session[2886]:   Value in failed request:  0x0
Jan  8 15:39:40 penny gnome-session[2886]:   Serial number of failed request:  19
Jan  8 15:39:40 penny gnome-session[2886]:   Current serial number in output stream:  20
Jan  8 15:39:40 penny gnome-session[2886]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GL Helper exited with code 256
Jan  8 15:39:40 penny gnome-session-c[2993]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-2E3GCThPiA: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
Jan  8 15:39:40 penny gnome-session-c[2993]: eglGetDisplay() failed
Jan  8 15:39:40 penny gnome-session[2886]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GLES Helper exited with code 256
Jan  8 15:39:40 penny gnome-session-c[2994]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-2E3GCThPiA: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session[2886]: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session[2886]:   Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session[2886]:   Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session[2886]:   Value in failed request:  0x0
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session[2886]:   Serial number of failed request:  19
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session[2886]:   Current serial number in output stream:  20
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session[2886]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GL Helper exited with code 256
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session-c[2996]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-2E3GCThPiA: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session-c[2996]: eglGetDisplay() failed
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session[2886]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GLES Helper exited with code 256
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session[2886]: gnome-session-binary[2886]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Der Kindprozess wurde mit Status 1 beendet
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session[2886]: gnome-session-binary[2886]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session-binary[2886]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Der Kindprozess wurde mit Status 1 beendet
Jan  8 15:39:45 penny gnome-session-binary[2886]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

- `dbus.service` log

```
● dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-01-08 15:38:17 CET; 59min ago
     Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
 Main PID: 924 (dbus-daemon)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
           └─924 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only

Jan 08 15:38:57 penny dbus-daemon[924]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Jan 08 15:39:03 penny dbus-daemon[924]: [system] Connection :1.72 (uid=0 pid=2472 comm="busctl monitor " label="unconfined") became a monitor.
Jan 08 15:39:14 penny dbus-daemon[924]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.78" (uid=1006 pid=2491 comm="lightdm --session-child 12 19 " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="ReleaseSession" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=1041 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")
Jan 08 15:39:25 penny dbus-daemon[924]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.79" (uid=1006 pid=2490 comm="lightdm --session-child 12 19 " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="ReleaseSession" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=1041 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")
Jan 08 15:39:35 penny dbus-daemon[924]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.80" (uid=1006 pid=2774 comm="lightdm --session-child 12 19 " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="ReleaseSession" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=1041 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")
Jan 08 15:39:47 penny dbus-daemon[924]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.97' (uid=112 pid=3081 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indic" label="unconfined")
Jan 08 15:39:47 penny dbus-daemon[924]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Jan 08 15:39:47 penny dbus-daemon[924]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.118' (uid=112 pid=3114 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined")
Jan 08 15:39:53 penny dbus-daemon[924]: [system] Monitoring connection :1.72 closed.
Jan 08 15:40:12 penny dbus-daemon[924]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

- output of `busctl monitor`

```
‣ Type=error  Endian=l  Flags=1  Version=1  Priority=0 Cookie=3  ReplyCookie=2
  Sender=org.freedesktop.DBus  Destination=:1.78
  ErrorName=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied  ErrorMessage="Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.78" (uid=1006 pid=2491 comm="lightdm --session-child 12 19 " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="ReleaseSession" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=1041 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")"
  MESSAGE "s" {
          STRING "Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.78" (uid=1006 pid=2491 comm="lightdm --session-child 12 19 " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="ReleaseSession" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=1041 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")";
  };
```

Does anybody know how this could be fixed?

**Update:**

I have "fixed" the issue by reinstalling ubuntu without deliting the home folder. Might not be a solution for everybody though..

Comment: Any chance you have a nvidiacard and nvidia driver on your System?

Comment: no, there is no seperate grahics card or driver installed